# How to monitor and act upon the change in a variable in a JRuby Program

Tags: ruby, event-handling, jruby

I developing a JRuby program whereby I set the value of a variable (var_a) to a text value on a web page.  I would like to take an action when the value of var_a changes.

Is there built-in functionality in JRuby to capture a change a value change event on a variable or does anyone have an elegant way of accomplishing this functionality.  Ultimately, I would like to utilize it in an observer pattern implementation.

Here's a little more background:

I'm actually using Celerity to screen scrape a page that updates the data every 60 seconds or so.  During a screen scraping session I set the value of a as follows:

```
a = browser.frame(:id, 'mainframe').div(:id, 'CurrentTime').text
```

Now what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
onchange(a) do puts a
```

Unfortunately, I don't think the onchange function exists. So I'm trying to come up with a and elegant ruby-like way of achieving this functionality.

Update:

Ok three ideas have been put forth:

1. Use Looping mechanism to compare new_value to original value.
2. Writing the value out to a file and comparing the new value to the "file" value.
3. Utilizing a setter approach - which I need to understand better.

Any other Rubyist have any input on these or suggestions on other alternatives.

Comment: Can you post some code?  I'm not quite understanding what you're doing.

Comment: Let me try to give a little more background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
new_a = browser.frame(:id, 'mainframe').div(:id, 'CurrentTime').text
if new_a != a
  # ... a changed, do something ...
end

a = new_a
# ... loop ...
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this approach would require the program to continually loop to compare a to new_a. I was hoping for a solution that did not require a continues loop.  Not sure its possible.   In any case, thanks for the input.

Comment: Ah, I thought maybe the program was continually looping.  If you absolutely can't have it loop, consider saving the value of `a` to a file and loading it back on subsequent runs.  The File class makes this pretty trivial: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/File

Comment: I like the file idea, but as I thought about it more, I guess some sort of while loop could also work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setter methods instead of variable to perform an action upon assignment:

```
# we want this to be triggered upon change
def a_has_changed val
  puts "a has changed and the new value is #{val.inspect}"
end

# this is a writer method mimicking assignment to a variable
def a= val
  unless @a == val
    @a = val # use ivar to store actual value
    a_has_changed val
  end
end

self.a = 3 # => a has changed and the new value is 3
self.a = 3 # outputs nothing
self.a = 4 # => a has changed and the new value is 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to do some homework this evening to brush up on setter methods.  I'm not quite getting how I would implement this approach in the context of a screen scraping script that would print out the current time every time the site updated the time one the webpage.